# How to know the duration of battery usage in one session?

Tags: battery, macbook-pro, charge, macos

I would like to know how long was my battery running since it's last charge. There is a built-in time-remaining counter but I would like a time-used counter.

Answer (score 34):

Starting with Mavericks (OS X 10.9), this is available in Activity Monitor. Open Activity Monitor from the /Applications/Utilities folder, and go to the Energy tab. The center pane of the statistics at the bottom of the window includes the amount of time since you last unplugged the charger, which appears shortly after you switch to battery power.

[image: Select the energy tab]
[image: Battery time at bottom of center pane]

Comment: That's great, but it shows the time since the macbook has been unplugged, whether it was used or in sleep mode. Is there a way to filter out sleep time ?

Comment: Not that I know of. One way to think of it is that it *is* using battery power when asleep, just not as much. I suppose if you really want to ignore sleep time, you could calculate it manually from that counter and data from `pmset -g log` on the command line, but that seems like more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Agreed. While it uses minimal battery power during sleep, the counter still adds up the time the laptop was set to sleep. For example, 5 hours of total sleep time counts as 5 hours since battery was discharged, even though it uses 1-2% power.

Comment: Does this include the time that it was completely shut down

Comment: [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210311/189683) might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

There is now a "Battery History" screen in recent versions of macOS:

[image: Battery history]

... and one can roughly count the number of hours from the chart, for example, on the example above, the last three blue bars are three hours of uptime, overall, my MacBook was turned on for roughly 6–7 hours on the example above.

I don't know why macOS doesn't provide a simpler way to get this single value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the app [Battery Truth](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/batterytruth/id1313428038?mt=12) on the Mac App Store. It costs $2.99 CAD and is supports English and Russian. Though it won't work if you Mac OS is older than 10.10.

The app will tell you:

1. How much longer the battery will last
2. What time the current charge will last you until
3. How long the battery will last on a full battery
4. How long the computer has been running on battery power for
5. And during that time how much of it the computer was asleep or running

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review