# How to tell total MacBook screen on time on battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, battery, macos

I'd like to know the total screen-on time since I plugged off my MacBook from the charger, but apparently there are no easily found stats for it.

Do I need an external app? I'm using MacBook Air 2015 with El Capitan.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See the original.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110780/how-to-know-the-duration-of-battery-usage-in-one-session

Comment: @JacoblovesRockstar there was already an answer here about that timer, but after my reply the person decided to remove it. The thing is, that shows the _total_ uptime (including sleep), not _screen on_ time.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that's something that Apple provides anywhere, however if you put in a little scripting work it's definitely doable. You can get the current brightness on the display with this command:

```
ioreg -l | awk '/ApplePanelRawBrightness/ {print $NF}'
```

A '0' result means the backlight is completely off. The upper limit depends on your specific hardware. You can get the highest possible number for your hardware with:

```
ioreg -l | awk '/AppleMaxBrightness/ {print $NF}'
```

You could set up a cron job to run that every minute, and record the result and current time, e.g. in a CSV file. You could then use a spreadsheet program to do the calculation. Or, you could use a higher level language like Python or Ruby to do the same thing and automate the calculation in your script. The latter would be my approach.

EDIT: I just noticed the 'on battery' part of the question - dunno how I managed to miss that. You can get a simple Yes or No answer to whether the AC adapter is connected using this command:

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType |grep Connected | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I would *+1* you already, if my dazzling 6 total points allowed me to, but looks like you'll get the 100 points in 2 days anyway.

Comment: And there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Activity Monitor app on the Launchpad, then click on Energy tab. There, you will see the stats of your Mac's battery down below.